# Observing progress of a distributed system

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, enterprise-architecture, distributed-computing

For a distributed system, there is a requirement of observing the progress of
smaller applications on distributed computers (runtime 5 - 20 minutes).

There is a web fronted, which right now only shows a list of those smaller
applications (called jobs), with the state of each of
them, like `preparing`, `running`, `finished`

So in web-ui, an administrator can see:

- name
- state
- starting time
- call parameters

from any computer in the network, possibly for the whole system.

Each of the properties is stored in the database, so each state change leads
to a call to write to the database. There might be thousends of those jobs 
at a time.

**Description of the distributed system:**

Central components, served at one location only:

- Database server (holding results of the jobs to runs statistics, have an overview of jobs run the last three month etc)
- Application server (glassfish, java, runs central server software)

Distributed components, each site has at least one, connected via internet / WAN area:
(probably about 20 sites, each has 1..4 Job controllers, each job controller runs about 20 jobs in parallel)

- Job-controller component (windows, c#, wcf, starts and observes small jobs)
- Small applications running tasks, started by Job-Controller (the jobs)

So, for a vague estimation:

```
20 sites * 4 Job-controllers * 20 jobs = 1600 jobs in parallel

each of which runs from 0 to 100 percent in about 5 minutes on average,
resulting in a progress update each 3 seconds.

giving 533 progress updates per second (over the internet)
```

Now the customer wants to see something like a progressbar for each of these
jobs.

At first, I thought this might lead to a high network traffic and to a vast amount of traffic on the database server.

I do not think that writing progress like 1%, 2%, 3% to the database is a good idea.
The runtime of those jobs is not very easy to be estimated good (so it is near enough 
to a real result), but each job can tell very well what his progress is.

**What would be a good architectural approach to observe progress of possibly thousends of those mini-jobs?** (Please note that a mixed infrastructure is given. There is the constraint that the system will be built upon that. so: Central glassfish + java and per site Windows + WCF + C#)

Right now I think that each Job-controller could update the progress of all jobs it controls every 10 seconds at once. Would that be an acceptable approach?

Comment: Maybe something like syslog in combination with logstash or the whole elk stack (elasticsearch, logstash, kibana). You won't get around the extra traffic as such but most of those modules can be installed relative leightweight on the client with a very responsive logserver running Redis, logstash and elastic.

Comment: I have to confess that I have not heard of the most of those things. Will investigate, thank you!

Comment: Some numbers would be good. 1, 10, 100, 1000 sites with controllers? Same with applications. Why is a database needed for the information on job progress? Can't you just put it in a ConcurrentHashMap and be done with it?

Comment: @Patrick Please have a look at the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a dashboard. There are a number of dashboard platforms out there that can be configured as to data sources, polling intervals, etc.

Let me suggest a rough design, while challenging some of your assumptions.

Assumption: You state that there is a central database that holds the *results* of each job. I don't see a requirement that it holds the status of each job while it is running.

Assumption: Detailed progress, at the % level, is not required. It is sufficient to show progress (or lack of progress, with a red flag).

Assumption: 1400 jobs, updating at 15 second intervals each (which is about 5% increments), is 5600 updates per minute, or 93 updates per second.

Assumption: The user interface component can extrapolate the speed of progress from recent updates and provide any smoothing of the dashboard animations.

For your architecture, consider using a distributed messaging framework such as Akka.NET. Each job reports its information and progress to an actor on its host machine. Host machines (I presume there is more than one host machine per site) report progress to a site machine, which forwards the job report to the central server. You may decide to update the database with progress, or not, as you see fit.

On the central server, the web server collects and summarizes the job information. For each job, you have the job identification, start time and parameters, most recent progress reported and progress rate, along with the time stamp. This summary is forwarded to the web page itself (via AJAX queries), where the UI takes each job and displays the progress bar and periodically updates it based on progress and progress rate.

This general approach to the web page design allows you to throttle progress updates as you tune the application, perhaps allowing the web page to focus on one or a few sites at a time for frequent updates. It also off-loads progress bar updates to the client where any kind of animation may be displayed.

Similarly, the use of the Akka.NET framework provides robust, fault tolerant distributed, reactive communication and updates. It will allow you to identify sites or hosts becoming unreachable, which should likely be displayed on the dashboard.

Comment: Most of your assumptions are correct. The customer wants % progress, but we are in a good position, so given recent progress and progress rate will give a good estimate. Aggregating the progress of all jobs for one controller will give a smaller progress rate though, especially if only one update for 10 seconds is provided. The UI can interpolate of course. BUT: We have a heterogenous system here, given java for the server and c# / wcf for the site-nodes. Will investigate on Akka.net. Thank you very much! Many good ideas and thoughts!

Comment: Akka (Java/Scala) and Akka.NET should work with each other. Instead of "aggregating", I should have said "concentrating", since we want full details to be sent up the hierarchy.